# How to watch BBC iPlayer outside UK

Tags: bbc, iplayer

I would like to watch BBC programmes from abroad. Anybody has a step by step process of how to accomplish just that?

I heard it will be possible to do just that some time in the second half of 2011 against payment.

### Additional edit

I suppose if I set a custom proxy to my browser connection I could watch it, right? Any **reliable/safe/free** proxy I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, the restriction on video sites such as the BBC is based on the IP address you are connecting from.  The only way around this is to connect from a UK IP address using a VPN or similar.  If you are leaving a machine at home, you can install [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) or similar.  It may cause an increase in latency and a decrease in bandwidth, but you might still be able to watch the video.

Comment: What if I only have a notebook that's always with me?

Comment: Then you would have to find some other machine in the UK to bounce your traffic off of.